# Appending an existing shared_ptr to a vector of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr

I have an existing vector of shared_ptr.  I want to search through that vector and if a condition is met, copy the respective shared_ptr to a new vector.

```
...
//vector< shared_ptr<Foo> > main_vec; // which already has some data
vector< shared_ptr<Foo> > output_vec{};

for ( auto iter = main_vec.begin() ; iter != main_vec.end() ; ++iter )
{
  if ( (*iter)->bar() == true )
    output_vec.push_back( *iter );
}

return output_vec;
...
```

I am not convinced the above is correct??  I am guessing that this will copy the shared_ptr but not increase the ref_count of the original, or am I over thinking this?  I'm pretty new to smart pointer.

TIA

Comment: why do you think it wont increase the reference count? You are creating a new reference. Also see [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: Copying a shared_ptr is increasing ref_count, that how shared_ptr works.

Comment: Why do you think that `(*iter)->bar() == true` is enough? `==` in this case also returns boolean. Maybe `( (*iter)->bar() == true ) == true`?

Comment: @Slava That's a stylistic choice. There's nothing inherently wrong with `== true`.

Comment: bar() is just some method in class foo, e.g. if a flag is set in that particular object.
copy_if looks perfect, with a lambda, many thanks for everyone's input.  I was concerned I was going to fall into the trap of copying a shared_ptr where neither have knowledge of each other, causing a double delete (copying isn't the work I'm looking for, but hope you understand what I mean!)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sure. Just like there is nothing inherently wrong with `== true ) == true` :)

Comment: @GreenaGiant `shared_ptr` is designed to be as safe and easy as possible. It seems you are concerned that you would have two sets of `shared_ptr`s owning the same object. It's a valid concern but only comes up when you initialize two or more `shared_ptr`s from raw pointers. Assigning between `shared_ptr`s is safe.

Comment: Understood, many thanks!  If there an equivalent "move_if" for the case where rather than "copy_if" into the new vector and leaving the original in tact, same but remove the respective element from the original? Cheers again

Comment: @eerorika That's true. While `== true` is probably not that useful, it's not hard to imagine it being a required or desired style. It can use to hint at `bar()`'s return type by convention or for the benefit of beginners or whatever other reason. But it's harder to imagine how chaining a series of `== true` would provide any benefit whatsoever (but I guess it's not impossible). However, that example was clearly written to mock OP. But by making it a mockery it also implies that his/her stand is necessarily the correct one. Simply stating that `== true` isn't necessary would have been fine.

Comment: Aside: `std::copy_if(main_vec.begin(), main_vec.end(), std::back_inserter(output_vec), [](auto foo){ return foo->bar(); });`

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you, but amazingly I was able to spot the redundancy without the insight provided by your subtle and exceedingly clever hint.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I disagree: I don't see anything mocking about Slava's comment. The series of `== true` is an excellent illustration that should hopefully trigger the understanding of *why* the `== true` is redundant. Simply stating its redundance is not as valuable. Sure, the comment may be amusing (which also adds inherent value to the comment), but that doesn't mean that someone has been mocked.

Comment: Just to chime in on the ==true conspiracy, in this case yet it is redundant.  Does my line manager enforce me using it for "code readability"....yes.  Meh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am not convinced the above is correct??

In accordance with your requirement specification, that's correct.

---

#### If you want to know more...

In particular, the statement:

```
output_vec.push_back( *iter );
```

has the following effects:

- `*iter` returns a reference to the smart pointer, i.e., `std::shared_ptr<Foo>&`.
- `output_vec.push_back` will create a **new** smart pointer, invoking the *copy-constructor*.
- The copy constructor of `std::shared_ptr`:

  > Constructs a shared_ptr which shares ownership of the object managed by r.

So the *reference counter* to the shared object will be increased.

#### Additional Notes...

Just for the sake of completeness, I would add some personal suggestions.

1) *For-each* loop can be expressed in a better way:

```
for (const auto& ptr : main_vec) {
  if (ptr->bar()) output_vec(ptr);
}
```

2) In particular, this for-each can be synthesized with [`copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: Many thanks.  I agree ranged for loops are nicer...boss doesn't; thinks it is "millennial code" lol.

Answer (score 3):

> I am guessing that this will copy the shared_ptr

Correct.

> but not increase the ref_count of the original

No, the copy constructor does increase the reference count. That's how shared pointers are designed to be copyable.

> I am not convinced the above is correct?

Then let me convince you: It is correct.